# Double free or corruption (out) Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, free, coredump, heap-corruption

When I execute the popAll function I get the following error:

double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)

I think I've narrowed down the source of the error to this function. IntegerStack is a simple ADT I made that contains an array called item and an int called numItems. popAll is in a seperate .c file that is part of the same directory as main, both .c files include a given header file with all function declarations. After looking through this forum for answers I saw people get this error when they try to free heap memory after it has already been freed, is that what I'm doing? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Below is my header file followed by my inplementation file followed by my test file.

```
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// IntegerStack.h
// Header file for the IntegerStack ADT
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#ifndef _Stack_H_INCLUDE_
#define _Stack_H_INCLUDE_


// Exported type --------------------------------------------------------------

// IntegerStack
// Exported reference type
typedef struct IntegerStackObj* IntegerStack;


// Constructors-Destructors ---------------------------------------------------

// newIntegerStack()
// Constructor for the IntegerStack ADT
IntegerStack newIntegerStack();

// freeIntegerStack()
// Destructor for the Stack ADT
void freeIntegerStack(IntegerStack* pS);


// ADT operations -------------------------------------------------------------

// isEmpty()
// Returns true (1) if S is empty, false (0) otherwise.
int isEmpty(IntegerStack S);

// push()
// Pushes x on top of S.
void push(IntegerStack S, int x);

// pop()
// Deletes and returns integer at top of S.
// Pre: !isEmpty(S)
int pop(IntegerStack S);

// peek()
// Returns integer at top of S.
// Pre: !isEmpty(S)
int peek(IntegerStack S);

// popAll()
// Resets S to the empty state.
void popAll(IntegerStack S);


// Other Operations -----------------------------------------------------------

// printIntegerStack()
// Prints a space separated list of integers in S, from top to bottom, to the
// filestream out.
void printIntegerStack(FILE* out, IntegerStack S);

// equals()
// Returns true (1) if S and T are matching sequences of integers, false (0) 
// otherwise.
int equals(IntegerStack S, IntegerStack T);


#endif


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// IntegerStack.c
// implementation file for the IntegerStack ADT
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include"IntegerStack.h"

void doubleItemArray(IntegerStack S);
int arrayIndex(int StackIndex);
// InitialSize
static const int InitialSize = 1;


// Exported type --------------------------------------------------------------

// IntegerStack
// Exported reference type
typedef struct IntegerStackObj {
    int* item;          // array of IntegerStack items
    int numItems;       // number of items in this integerStack
    int physicalSize;   // current length of underlying array
}IntegerStackObj;


// Constructors-Destructors ---------------------------------------------------

// newIntegerStack()
// Constructor for the IntegerStack ADT
IntegerStack newIntegerStack() {
    IntegerStack S = (IntegerStackObj*)malloc(sizeof(IntegerStackObj));
    S-> item = (int*)calloc(InitialSize, sizeof(int));
    S->numItems = 0;
    S->physicalSize = InitialSize;
    return S;
}

// freeIntegerStack()
// Destructor for the Stack ADT
void freeIntegerStack(IntegerStack* pS) {
    if (pS != NULL && *pS != NULL) {
        free((*pS)->item);
        free(*pS);
        *pS = NULL;
    }
}


// ADT operations -------------------------------------------------------------

// isEmpty()
// Returns true (1) if S is empty, false (0) otherwise.
int isEmpty(IntegerStack S) {
    if (S == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "IntegerList Error: isEmpty() called on NULL             
        IntegerStack reference");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return (S->numItems == 0);
}

// push()
// Pushes x on top of S.
void push(IntegerStack S, int x) {
    int i;
    if (S == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "IntegerList Error: push() called on NULL IntegerStack reference");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // increase physical size of array if necessary
    if ((S->numItems) == (S->physicalSize)) {
        doubleItemArray(S);
    }

    // shift elements in stack to the right to add 1
    for (i = (S->numItems); i >= 0; i--) {
        S->item[arrayIndex(i + 1)] = S->item[arrayIndex(i)];
    }
    S->item[arrayIndex(1)] = x;
    S->numItems++;
}

// pop()
// Deletes and returns integer at top of S.
// Pre: !isEmpty(S)
int pop(IntegerStack S) {
    int num;
    int i;
    // check !isEmpty(S) 
    if (S == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "IntegerList Error: pop() called on NULL IntegerStack reference");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // set num to the returned int before it is overwritten
    num = S->item[arrayIndex(1)];       
    for (i = 1; i <= (S->numItems); i++) {      //check the     i............................
        S->item[arrayIndex(i - 1)] = S->item[arrayIndex(i)];
    }
    S->numItems--;
    return num;
}

// peek()
// Returns integer at top of S.
// Pre: !isEmpty(S)
int peek(IntegerStack S) {
    // check if S is empty first
    if (S == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "IntegerList Error: peek() called on NULL IntegerStack reference");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return S->item[arrayIndex(1)];
}

// popAll()
// Resets S to the empty state.
void popAll(IntegerStack S) {
    // check if S is empty first to prevent potential seg fault
    if (S == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "IntegerList Error: popAll() called on NULL IntegerStack reference");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // free the item array, and set numItems to 0
    free((S->item));
    S->numItems = 0;
}


// Other Operations -----------------------------------------------------------

// printIntegerStack()
// Prints a space separated list of integers in S, from top to bottom, to the
// filestream out.
void printIntegerStack(FILE* out, IntegerStack S) {
    // check if S is empty first
    if (S == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "IntegerList Error: printIntegerStack() called on     NULL IntegerStack reference");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= (S->numItems); i++) {
        fprintf(out, "%d ", (S->item[arrayIndex(i)]));
    }
    fprintf(out, " \n");        // sets it up to print on the next line when the annother thing needs to be printed
}

// equals()
// Returns true (1) if S and T are matching sequences of integers, false (0) 
// otherwise.
int equals(IntegerStack S, IntegerStack T) {
    int i, eq;
    if (S == NULL || T == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "IntegerList Error: equals() called on NULL IntegerStack reference");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    eq = ((S->numItems) == (T->numItems));
    for (i = 1; eq && i <= (S->numItems); i++) {
        eq = ((S->item[arrayIndex(i)]) == (T->item[arrayIndex(i)]));
    }
    return eq;
}

// doubleItemArray
// Doubles the physical size of the underlying array L->item.
void doubleItemArray(IntegerStack S) {
    int i;
    int* newArray;
    int* oldArray = S->item;
    S->physicalSize *= 2;
    newArray = (int*)calloc(S->physicalSize, sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < (S->numItems); i++) {
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    }
    S->item = newArray;
    free(oldArray);
}

// arrayIndex()
// transforms an IntegerList index to an Array index
int arrayIndex(int StackIndex) {
    return StackIndex - 1;
}







//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// IntegerStackTest.c
// Test client for the IntegerStack ADT
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include"IntegerStack.h"
int main() {
    int i, n = 45;
    IntegerStack A = newIntegerStack();
    IntegerStack B = newIntegerStack();

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        push(A, i);
        push(B, i);
    }

    printIntegerStack(stdout, A);
    printIntegerStack(stdout, B);
    printf("%s\n", equals(A, B) ? "true" : "false");

    for (i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        printf("%d ", pop(B));
    }
    printf("\n");
    printIntegerStack(stdout, B);
    printf("%s\n", equals(A, B) ? "true" : "false");

    for (i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        printf("%d ", peek(A));
        pop(A);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printIntegerStack(stdout, A);
    printf("%s\n", equals(A, B) ? "true" : "false");

    popAll(A);
    printf("%s\n", equals(A, B) ? "true" : "false");
    popAll(B);
    printf("%s\n", equals(A, B) ? "true" : "false");

    freeIntegerStack(&A);
    freeIntegerStack(&B);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This function is supposed to reset S to the empty state. Instead it is giving me an ulcer.

Comment: Needs more code. Have you debugged to see why the same object is being freed twice? Setting the pointer to null would of course stop it from happening, but bigger issue may remain, which is why the object is used after freeing. At least for freeing it again

Comment: I don't know why the same item is being freed twice, as you said, when I set S->item =NULL it fixed the error. However, for this project I can't have any memory leaks, so I still need to free item first.

Comment: Debug it. That’s how you’ll find out why it happens twice. It’s impossible to say from this code since this one is not doing the actual management of the objects. And of course you need to free it first.  (Also hiding pointers behind typedefs is often bad and confusing)

Comment: If you want help, you need to post enough code so that we can reproduce the problem. The posted code is not sufficient. BTW: In a comment you say "..when I set S->item =NULL it fixed the error" Np, it didn't **fix** the error, it just hides the error.

Comment: I guess you are calling PopAll () twice :/ the S->item = NULL; should be after the free, not before or instead ;)

Comment: Without seeing the code for `newIntegerStack()`, `push`, `pop`, and `popAll` there is no way anyone can tell. However, I suspect `pop` and `popAll` have a `--count` or the equivalent somewhere near the beginning the decrements an index related to a pointer or stack storage that is not being decrement before you call `free((S->item));` resulting in you calling `free((S->item));` on a block of memory that has already been freed. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You only test if `S` is `NULL`, but you free `S->item`. Also check if `S->item` is `NULL` (or if you did it correctly, if `S->numItems==0`).

And as SamiKuhmonen said, you should debug your code. If you're under Linux, look at [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [GDB](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_toc.html). Valgrind help you to find memory managment error and memory leaks. While GDB help you to see what appens during the excution of your code.

Comment: Sorry but this answer is wrong. Checking for `S->item` being null is not relevant. If it is null  the error "double free or corruption (out) Aborted (core dumped)" would not happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you have memory issue, please use Valgrind. It's really usefull !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but I changed the last two lines in the push() function from:
    `S`->item[arrayIndex(1)] = x;
    `enter code here`S->numItems++;

```
`enter code here`//to:

`enter code here`S->item[S->numItems] = x;
`enter code here`S->numItems++;
```

and now the whole program is functioning properly. thank you so much for your help.